# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery using comparision operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 drop down where i need to populate 2nd drop down based on 1st Drop down,I have added 'all' option to 1st drop down when user selected 'all' need to populate the 2nd drop down The query i have used is

```
   SELECT DISTINCT [Year] from dbo.[tbl_A] 
   WHERE [TyreSize] IN
   (CASE 'All'
    WHEN 'All' Then (SELECT DISTINCT [Tyresize] FROM dbo.[tbl_A])
    WHEN '27.00 R 49' Then (SELECT DISTINCT Tyresize FROM dbo.[tbl_A]                     
    WHERE [TyreSize] IN ('27.00 R 49'))
   END)
```

Comment: can you explain the logic and the input parameters, please? how are you passing the selected value of the 1st dropdown to this query?

Comment: That case makes no sense at all. The string literal 'All' is always equals to 'All', i.e. you'll always get the first WHEN. Then you do SELECT without any correlation, which means a lot of rows will be returned, but only one value is allowed here.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR` instead of `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Year] from dbo.[tbl_A] 
WHERE 
    @All = 'All' OR -- @All is your parameter
    [TyreSize] IN ('27.00 R 49')
```

Comment: what's `@All` ?

Comment: I think He has variable to store `All` string.

Comment: What you mean here then ? `CASE 'ALL' WHEN 'ALL' then ...` @HarinathDevineni

Comment: Without `@All`, how do you store value selected in 1st drop down, @HarinathDevineni?

Comment: 'All' is the Parameter,Suppose if i have tyresize a,b,c if the user want to select all in dropdown

Comment: @Ted, `@All` doesn't bother me. It can be any variable storing user selection.

Comment: @HarinathDevineni Okay Change your parameter with `@All`

Answer (score 1):

```
   declare @status varchar(20)
   set @status='All'
   select * from t1 where ID in
   (Select (Case when @status<>'All' then @status else (select distinct id from t1) end) AS test  from t1)
```